# "Of/from/with" in my sentence

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use in my sentences? Is each of them correct?

1. ''Cheesesticks are made of/with/from cheese and breadcrumbs.''
2. ''This soup is made with/of/from peas, eggs, cheese and vegetables.''

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/made-of-and-made-from?rq=1) answer your question? Also [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/why-is-wine-made-from-grapes-but-tables-are-made-of-wood?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a highly knowledgeable by @snailplane.

Comment: highly knowledgeable answer* ...

Comment: If "made of" expresses composition, while "made from" expresses transformation, both can be used in my examples, if I understand correctly. "Made with" wasn't mentioned, though.

Comment: As far as I understood, this will be a case of composition. Hence it should be "of". But again I am not one hundred percent sure.

Comment: "Made with" expresses "using these ingredients". I would prefer _from_, but all are possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one to answer as they are very similar. All can be correct and are often largely interchangeable.

Cheesesticks are made of cheese - The main ingredient of cheesesticks is cheese. The purpose here is to express the state of the cheesestick after it has been made. The cheese is likely to be largely unchanged in the final product. "The chair is made of wood" - There is a wooden chair. The wood is still there as wood, it has just had it's shape changed.

Cheesesticks are made from cheese - Cheese exists and it is turned into cheesesticks. The purpose here is to express the transformation of cheese and breadcrumbs into cheesesticks. The cheese is likely in a different form in the final product. It is now a cheesestick instead of being cheese and breadcrumbs. "Paper is made from wood" - There was wood and now there is paper. Paper is not recognisable as wood anymore. It is a new product.

Cheesesticks are made with cheese - Cheese is used when cheesesticks are made. The prupose here is to express that cheese is used in the process of making the cheesesticks. "The soup was made with eggs" -  The soup could have been made without using eggs but eggs were used.

As you can see these are almost the same. The subtle difference comes from the context in which you are talking about the process.

You can also use "made out of" in place of "made of":

"The chair is made out of wood" - There is a wooden chair.