# "Made out of", "made of" and "made with"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I understand the phrases *made of* and *made from* from the questions and answers provided [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/made-of-and-made-from) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24187/made-of-or-made-from).

Yet I came across three more phrases: *made out of*, *made of*, and *made with* which I think are related to the subject in question.

Would you please help me understand how to differentiate these phrases too? And how is their usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems ...

> *made of* = *made out of* - [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1#make_1__4) puts *of* in parenthesis i.e. it's optional.

*Made with* is less common in the context we are thinking. It means to proceed with doing, showing of as in *make with music. ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-with#make-with_1)) * I also notice *make with love* on the SERPs.

And to conclude, we generally use *made of* when the original material remains what it is and *made from* when the original material changes its avatar. You already mentioned those two questions.

[Good read on BBC.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page29.shtml)

Comment: My confusion is this: should we say that this object is made with iron, glass, wood, etc. or this object is made from (out of) iron, glass, wood, etc. that is when there are many components that are used to make an object.

Comment: Of course, if the new thing keeps its original thing (ingredient?) intact, it's made **of**. *The house is made **of** bricks.** If the original material loses its original shape, texture or form, it's **from**. *A paper is made **from** trees.* Good read here on BBC http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page29.shtml So, in your case where multiple things are used to make something, it's made **OF** because the metals remain intact. http://answers.ask.com/business/constructions_and_materials/what_is_stainless_steel_made_of

Comment: As you can see on only this page: http://indianfood.about.com/od/sweetsanddesserts/tp/milkdesserts.htm I found to be used all: with, from, of. Maybe it doesn’t matter what preposition we use?

Comment: @LucianSava In food (dishes) it talks about the ingredients used. *With* is okay that way. But then let it make easy for you. Ask yourself, can you **identify** the fruit in the dish as it is in its original form? If the answer is *yes* then go for *of* and if you cannot make it out by its appearance (and not taste), it's *from.* :)