# Are 'from' & 'with' interchangeable in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

We use **"Made from + material"** (when the material changes its nature, i.e., the original substance can't be seen or left:

> The lotion is made from aloe Vera.

But I have read : "In short, "made with X" means that X is one of the ingredients or materials that went into the object." 
https://tinyurl.com/yddlxx2f

It means we can use : **"Made with + ingredients"** :

> The lotion is made with aloe Vera.

Are *'from'* and *'with'* interchangeable in the given sentence?

Comment: @ColleenV, I know the difference between *"made from"* and *"made of"*. But my question is different. It's about *"made from"* vs. *"made with"* in a given sentence.

Comment: My mistake for rushing. there are a number of overlapping questions but I think this is the relevant one https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24535/9161 and frankly, I'm going to go ahead a downvote because you could have done that search yourself before you asked.

Comment: There is room to improve this question, to make it quite special and worthy of interest. Please do not disappoint.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question. I have seen that usage of 'made with' in one of the comments here : https://tinyurl.com/yddlxx2f