# made from/of vs made with?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

please clarify , if we talk about food is it acceptable to use 'made from' like 'this milkshake was made/of from bananas and milk'? As I found on Cambridge english we should use 'made with' when talking about food, but I saw a couple examples on different resources with 'from/of'.
Also if I want to ask how a particular dish or a drink is usually made, how to do that correctly? is 'What is this dish usually made with?' correct?
Thanks

Comment: _Made from_ [these ingredients] seems fine to me. I would use _made with_ to refer to one particular ingredient, as in _This cake was made with butter_ (as opposed to margarine).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Made out of", "made of" and "made with"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24535/made-out-of-made-of-and-made-with)

Comment: Each is possible, and I wouldn't worry too much about being wrong, but they have slightly different connotations, e.g. "This burger is made of beef", "This cheese is made from sheep's milk", "This brownie is made of flour, eggs, and sugar", "This coffee is made from freshly roasted beans"... "of" or "from" sound ok with your milkshake, but you couldn't say "this coffee is made of beans". Cambridge English's rule seems a bit prescriptive and not reflecting how people talk about food.

Comment: I dunno, "X is *made from* Y and Z" implies some kind of transformation or process to me.  Mineral oil is made *from* crude oil, but it isn't made *of* or *with* crude oil.