# "made of" or "made with"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> The hourglass was made **of** glassbulbs.
>   The hourglass  was made **with**  glassbulbs.

Which sentence  is more common?
I am so confused with their usages.

Comment: When talking about the physical composition of an object, neither preposition is incorrect. I can say "The clock is made of wood" or "The clock is made from wood."

Comment: The OP does not use 'from' at all! @J.R. You missed 'with'

Comment: @MaulikV - Good catch! I guess you can use three prepositions. "The clock is made with wood" works, too. I think there's a duplicate or related question somewhere; I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @MaulikV - [This one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/why-is-wine-made-from-grapes-but-tables-are-made-of-wood/11246) is the related question I was trying to remember.

Comment: *Made of*, though not incorrect, has more of an implication that there aren't other materials involved. *Made with* can indicate just one or some of the materials.

Answer (score 14):

Cheese is made from milk. (It changes form.)

The table is made of wood. (It doesn't change form.)

The cake was made with flour, eggs and sugar.

The hourglass was made with glass bulbs.

Comment: You could make an hourglass of lightbulbs. http://www.instructables.com/id/HOURGLASS-DIY-out-of-Light-Bulbs/

Comment: @MatthewWhited  The English language is pretty flexible, so of/from/with - a little ambiguous sometimes. I prefer 'with', since the original purpose of the lightbulbs has been transformed.

Comment: with = partial composition, of = full composition. http://www.instructables.com/id/HOURGLASS-DIY-out-of-Light-Bulbs/ is made _with_ or _from_ lightbulbs, but not _of_ them

Comment: The purpose of wood would be changed when making a chair ;)

Comment: @MatthewWhited A common use for wood is for making furniture. Lightbulbs aren't normally used for hourglasses. That's why "with" sounds better to me.

Comment: There are some situations where any of the three would work: *Made **with/of/from** all-natural ingredients*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes. English is getting more and more flexible as a language.

Answer (score 8):

> The hourglass was made of glassbulbs.

Glass bulbs are part of the hourglass.

> The hourglass was made with glassbulbs.

Glass bulbs were used in making the hourglass.  This can strongly imply that glass bulbs are part of the hourglass (because hourglasses have glass bulbs), but in other similar sentences *with X* might just reference a tool or an ingredient used in making.

E.g. *The book was made with a printer* - A printer is not part of the book.

Comment: I think "made of" indicates not just that the glass bulbs are part of the hourglass, but that they're the *principal* part. For example, I wouldn't describe a cake as being "made of sugar" (except hyperbolically).

Comment: And for the reason @ruakh mentions, ‘made with’ is useful for the lesser components: a cake is made *with* sugar; also, my computer was made with several kinds of jacks on the back.  (There's a passage about this kind of quibbling in Dorothy Sayers' novel *Murder Must Advertise*.)

Comment: Your printer example sounds a little awkward to me. I'd be inclined to say instead "The book was made using a printer".

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct. If you want to emphasize on the things used to build it, tge second sentence is more proper. But if you want to convey that of what material the hourglass is made, the first one is a better choice.

This is copied from my cell phone Merriam Websters advanced learners dictionary:

make [I]

/ˈmeık/  verb  , makes, made /ˈmeıd/, mak·ing

1 [  + obj  ]

1 a : to build, create, or produce (something) by work or effort

.
   .
   .

- often followed by ***with*** to  describe the things that are used
  to produce something:

  She made the sauce with cheese and other    ingredients.
- often followed by ***of*** to describe the material    that forms
  something:

  The box is made of wood. [=it is a    wood/wooden box;the material
  used to produce the box was wood]

  The topping is made entirely of cheese. [=the topping consists
  entirely of cheese]
- often followed by ***from*** to describe the source of a product:

  Cheese is made from milk.