# Which is correct: A cellphone is made of a variety of materials or A cellphone is made from a variety of materials

Tags: phrase-usage

Which is correct:

1. A cellphone is made of a variety of materials.
2. A cellphone is made from a variety of materials.

Wine is made from grapes. / The chair is made of wood. If it is in the situation of making cellphones, which is correct?

Comment: Also, I would use "Cell phones are" rather than "A cell phone is", because this applies to all cell phones (there is no possible cell phone that is made of just one input material).

Comment: You may find some guidance here: [Why is wine made "from" grapes while a table is made "of" wood?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/why-is-wine-made-from-grapes-but-tables-are-made-of-wood)

Answer (score 1):

You should use (1), 'made of', although many people will not notice if you use (2). A cell phone is made of 40 percent metals, 40 percent plastics and 20 percent ceramics and trace materials.

Strictly, we use 'made **of**' to talk about the materials of which a finished article is made, so my desk is made of wood, and my sister's wedding ring is made of gold. Consider 'made of' to mean 'composed of'.

We use 'made **from**' to talk about something that has been transformed from one form to another: I have a candle holder made from an old wine bottle, and my kids are playing in a tent made from bed sheets.

Comment: Wasn't the cellphone transformed from a variety of materials into its current form?